# error in RichTextBox right to left option

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I tried to make the `RichTextBox` to show text from left to right. I changed the `RightToLeft` option to YES, but when I typed `1qwerty0`, it showed me `qwerty01`. I don't know if this is an error or not. If it's not an error then could anyone tell me how to do it correctly?
Here, take a look at the problem: [image]

Edit:
If I edit the text at runtime (click to the textbox and type it out) then it's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way is using `SelectionAlignment` instead of `RightToLeft`

Change `RightToLeft` to `No` and use `SelectionAlignment` in `FormLoad` Like This :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        }
```

Comment: thank you, it does work. But after every time I click a button, the textbox automatically turns back to Left to Right. I can handle this by set it to Right to Left again, but is there a better way?

Comment: nevermind. I use the event `TextChanged` to solve it.

Comment: But it work for me with `richTextBox1.AppendText("sometext");` , maybe your appending has problem!!